# file path is not passed correctly while entering in save as window using python script

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using python code to enter filepath in the save as window which will be opened when clicked on internal software we use.
I am passing the value as C:\XYZ.txt
but when it enters in the window it is entering the value as c;\xyz.txt for which the windows is throwing path is incorrect.
Below is the code i am using

```
def save_file_as(FileName):
    __title = "Save As"
 result = autoIt.WinWaitActive(__title, "", 60)
 if result == 1:
 print("Enter the unique name to save the file: " + FileName)
 result = autoIt.ControlSend(__title, "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", FileName)
        if result == 1:
           result = autoIt.ControlClick(__title, '', "[text:&Save]")
```

Comment: Have you tried `C:/XYZ.txt`? On windows you can use forward slashes as well for file paths.

Comment: Sorry I missed a part in this. I am passing the file path from robot frame work.I am passing the value as C:\\

Comment: And also in my case if i give forward slash it throws me an error file path is not valid

Comment: In the log, you see the value of `FileName` as being correct, right? E.g. the log message is "Enter the unique name to save the file:  C:\XYZ.txt", with the colon character?

Comment: Yes the log file i could see that but while entering it is not giving the same value